# How do I add additional parameters to query string of a Firefox Search Plugin?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, xml, search-engines, firefox-profile

I have just installed the [DuckDuckGo](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/duckduckgo-ssl/) add-on in Firefox 11.0, running on XP SP 3.

I would like to add additional parameters to the query string.  However, any changes I make are not reflected in the query string when doing a search.

I found the duckduckgo.xml file at C:\Documents and Settings\User Name\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\Profile Name.default\searchplugins.  I opened it up with Notepad++ and added the line for kl=uk-en:

```
<SearchPlugin xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/" xmlns:os="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
<os:ShortName>DuckDuckGo</os:ShortName>
<os:Description>Search DuckDuckGo (SSL)</os:Description>
<os:InputEncoding>UTF-8</os:InputEncoding>
<os:Image width="16" height="16">data:image/x-icon;base64, -Removed to shorten-</os:Image>
<os:Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="https://duckduckgo.com/">
  <os:Param name="q" value="{searchTerms}"/>
  <os:Param name="kl" value="uk-en"/>
</os:Url>
</SearchPlugin>
```

However, the kl=uk-en parameter does not appear in the query string when searching (despite several Firefox restarts).

Comment: Well the XML changes do appear to be reflected now when searching.  However, is there any explanation as to why any changes that are made to this file are not reflected straight away (after saving the file and Firefox is restarted)?  Does Firefox only read the XML file periodically, or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably the xml data is stored to some internal sqlite db on install, so you would have to uninstall and reinstall the search plugin.